# Java Polygons in a Hashmap

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java.

What I want to do is put Polygons into a Hashmap and use them somewhere else.

*my_polygons* is a property in my class:

```
private final static HashMap my_polygons = new HashMap();
```

When I build polygons from points, I put polygons into *my_coordinates*:

```
// in a loop:
    Polygon my_polygon = new Polygon();
    // ...some code to build my polygon
    my_polygons.put(polygon_id, my_polygon);
```

...and than, in another part of the code, I want to reuse all these polygons within another loop:

```
// within another loop:
    Object polygon_object = my_polygons.get(polygon_id);
```

My question is, polygon_object is an "Object" and I need to convert it into a polygon, how can I do it? Or is it wrong to use a **hashmap** for this operation? I will use the polygon for the following operation:

```
my_polygon.contains(x, y);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use generics to your `HashMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a raw `HashMap` :

```
private final static HashMap my_polygons = new HashMap();
```

use a parameterized type (I'm assuming the polygon identifier is an integer) :

```
private final static HashMap<Integer,Polygon> my_polygons = new HashMap<Integer,Polygon>();
```

This way `my_polygons.get(polygon_id);` will return a `Polygon`.